# Multiple TCP sockets in C

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, tcp

Does anyone have guidance on how one should go about opening many sockets, listening on them, and doing send/receive on each? Currently I'm looking at three high level options

1. Make a thread per connection
2. Make a single thread for all connections
3. Don't split connection handling out of the main thread

I'm making a mail server like program and I can't find any best practices on the subject. Nor can I find any wisdom on the pros/cons of each of the above options.

Comment: high level options in C?

Comment: Your question seems to be mostly about how to handle I/O on multiple sockets. You could use a thread per connection, you could use nonblocking I/O, or maybe asynchronous I/O, or do I/O multiplexing with `select()` and / or `poll()`. The latter is usually the preferred approach. I suggest you go through chapter 14 of *Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment* to learn about each approach, and its pros and cons. And while you're at it, read the rest of the book, because it's a great book :)